# Get type of generic type inside a List in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have the below function:

```
    public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> lst){
          if (T instanceof String) {
          // Do something       
          }
          if (T instanceof Integer) {
          // Do something   
          }
    }
```

Inside this function, i want to know if <T> is String or Integer so i wonder if there is a way to discover its type? I used the above code but it generated error

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the instanceof operator doesn't work on T. You'll have to actually get an element from the list, like lst.get(0) instanceof String

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not find the type of `T` as the type information is erased. Check [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more details. But if the list is not empty, you can get an element from the list and can find out using `instanceof` and `if else`

Comment: suppose you get an element and it is null, then instanceof will not help you

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible in Java due to [erasure](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2004/09/puzzling-through-erasure-answer.html). What most people do instead is add a type token. Example:

```
public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> list, Class<T> listElementType) {
}
```

There are certain situations where reflection can get at the type parameter, but it's for cases where you've pre-set the type parameter. For example:

```
public class MyList extends List<String> {
    private List<String> myField;
}
```

In both of those cases reflection can determine the List is of type String, but reflection can't determine it for your case. You'd have to use a different approach like a type token.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to determine this due to [erasure](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2004/09/puzzling-through-erasure-answer.html), which means that the  parameter is not stored in the code. However you can either pass an extra parameter specifying what type the list is:

```
public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> lst, Class<T> listElementType) {
```

}

or you can determine the type of each element at runtime:

```
public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> lst){
  for (Object elem:lst) {
      if (elem instanceof String) {
      // Do something       
      }
      if (elem instanceof Integer) {
      // Do something   
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics are called "erasures" because they exist at compile time only and are removed by compiler. So, there is no way to determine the generic type of collection. The only way to do it for non-empty lists is to take the first element and determine its type.

This is almost the same solution that was suggested by DJClayworth, but I think that there is no need to check each element of the list. If you are sure that the list is created with generics (new ArrayList() or new LinkedList() etc) all its element are guaranteed to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run function of the object, you can do:

```
public <T> void putList(String key, List<T> lst){
    for(T object : lst){
         if(object instanceof String) {
             doSomething(((String)object).doForString())
         }
         if(object instanceof Integer) {
             doSomething(((Integer)object).doForInteger())
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the instanceof operator.

That said, generic operations should be, well, generic, so be wary of changing behaviour based on type.

Comment: the instanceof operator won't work on generic type parameters like T

Comment: @Visage that's a good point. @Teja Kantamneni said the same in his answer, so long as the list is not empty

Comment: Indeed. And if the list is empty then does the nominal type of its non existent contents matter?> One for the questioner to answer, I suppose...

Comment: @Visage: what if the first element is null? then it would not match even if T is String

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment - if the list is empty then would functionality change based on its nominal type? Would you process a List with no Strings differently from a List with no Integers?

Answer (score -1):

```
Type genericType = lst.getType();

if(genericType instanceof ParameterizedType){
    ParameterizedType aType = (ParameterizedType) genericType;
    Type[] fieldArgTypes = aType.getActualTypeArguments();
    for(Type fieldArgType : fieldArgTypes){
        Class fieldArgClass = (Class) fieldArgType;
        System.out.println("fieldArgClass = " + fieldArgClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Neil. thanks for your answer, but i could not find the getType() method of lst List

Comment: That's because there is no such thing.