# How to determine the content type of a list at runtime

Tags: java, list, casting

I have an Observer that is expecting two possible objects from an observable: `List<Cat>` or `List<Orange>`, mutually exclusive. How might I distinguish which data type was passed to
`update(Observable observable, Object data)`? I cannot use `if(data instanceof List<Cat>)` because of type erasure at runtime?

Comment: You should retrieve the first element in the `List` and verify the type by using `instanceof` operator.

Comment: may be object.getClass()

Comment: @Mendoza This will only inform you if the object falls under that hierarchy, not if its exactly that type

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list) post?

Comment: @VinceEmigh that's probably enough for OP. If you want an exact accurate option, use `object.getClass().equals(Orange.class)`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks @LuiggiMendoza, that was an awesome observation. I didn't see it. Thank you so much. Will you please repost as a response so I may accept it? Here is what I did: `Object obj = ((List<Object>)data).get(0);
   if(obj instanceof String)...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get type of generic type inside a List in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155252/get-type-of-generic-type-inside-a-list-in-java), specifically check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4155327/474189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the first element in your `List` (assuming is not empty) and test the type of the element retrieved. You may use `instanceof` operator to see if the object is in the class hierarchy of the desired class, but if you want a more accurate test, use `getClass().equals(YourClass.class)`.

```
public void foo(List<Object> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        Object object = list.get(0);
        //using instanceof
        if (object instanceof Cat) {
        }
        if (object instanceof Orange) {
        }
        //using getClass().equals
        if (object.getClass().equals(Cat.class)) {
        }
        if (object.getClass().equals(Orange.class)) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Duncan refer to [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526/1065197). IMO you should not program that defensively unless it is necessary. In this case, passing any `null` value should be an error and handled out of here. It may be (or not) a flaw or not depending on the design and on the current experience of the software designers/architects.

Comment: +1, However note that if you intend to store null values in your list (see [*Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/271526/1065197) for why this probably isn't a great idea), be aware that `instanceof` will return false on `null` input.

Comment: Just curious: is comparing classes more accurate than checking `instanceof`?

Comment: @KatedralPillon yes, because you can have `PussyCat extends Cat` and `PussyCat pussyCat = new PussyCat();`, then `pussyCat instanceof Cat` will return `true` but `pussyCat.getClass().equals(Cat.class)` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

i know this is not what really PO want but i think this may helpful. Wrapers can help in this situation. you can create two Class and one interface:

```
interface SpecialList<T> {
  T get(int i);
  void add(T item);
}


class CatList implements SpecialList<Cat> {
  private List<Cat> list;
...
}

class OrangeList implements SpecialList<Orange> {
  private List<Cat> list;
...
}
```

then Observable can return a SpecialList object. in this case `instance of` will work.